# Should WebSocket server only handle GET requests?

Tags: websocket

I have a WebSocket server written which only handles upgrade requests which are GET requests. If a POST or any other kind of request with the required headers comes it is handled by a HTTP server.

In the [specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455#section-1.3) it is not stated explicitly that the WebSocket upgrade request **should**  be a GET request.
If the upgrade request is not a GET request should the server handle it as a WebSocket upgrade request, should it pass it to be handled by the HTTP server or should it respond to it with a status code like `400 Bad Request` ?

Could this be a design decision where the server decides not to handle methods which are not GET requests?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From [section 4.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455#section-4.1) (Client Requirements) of the webSocket specification, it says this:

> The method of the request MUST be GET, and the HTTP version MUST
> be at least 1.1

And, then later in [section 4.2.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455#section-4.2.1) (Reading the Client's Opening Handshake) of the webSocket specification, it says this:

> The client's opening handshake consists of the following parts.  If
> the server, while reading the handshake, finds that the client did
> not send a handshake that matches the description below (note that as
> per [RFC2616], the order of the header fields is not important),
> including but not limited to any violations of the ABNF grammar
> specified for the components of the handshake, the server MUST stop
> processing the client's handshake and return an HTTP response with an
> appropriate error code (such as 400 Bad Request).

> 1. An HTTP/1.1 or higher GET request, including a "Request-URI"
>    [RFC2616] that should be interpreted as a /resource name/
>    defined in Section 3 (or an absolute HTTP/HTTPS URI containing
>    the /resource name/).

So, there are multiple places where it says the http request must be a GET.

---

As for your specific questions:

> Should WebSocket server only handle GET requests?

Yes, a webSocket connection will always start with a GET request, not a POST or any other method.

> If the upgrade request is not a GET request should the server handle it as a WebSocket upgrade request, should it pass it to be handled by the HTTP server or should it respond to it with a status code like 400 Bad Request ?

As described in the above reference portion of the specfication, the server should respond with a status code like 400 Bad Request.

> Could this be a design decision where the server decides not to handle methods which are not GET requests?

Yes.